# Logic and adjunctions with ideals in ring theory

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, adjoint-functors, categorical-logic

Studying ring theory, I remarked two things in the context of ideals that look like some interpretation of a logic in the ideals of a ring (I never studied this subject so my formulation is quite imprecise).

First, there is the "comma operation" on ideals, characterized by $J ⊆ I:S ⇔ JS ⊆ I$.

And then there is the "content of a polynomial ideal" construction. This came from studying Gauss' lemma as stated in the [general version on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_(polynomial)#General_version). Let us define the *content* $\DeclareMathOperator{\cont}{cont}\cont(U)$ of an ideal $U ⊆ R[x]$ as the ideal generated by all the coefficients of all the elements of $U$.

Then we get, for any ideal $I ⊆ R$, the equivalence of $\cont(U) ⊆ I$ and $U ⊆ I[X]$. We also have this sort of "universal property" of the product of ideals, relatively to primes : $IJ ⊆ \mathfrak{p} ⇔ I ⊆ \mathfrak{p} ∨ J ⊆ \mathfrak{p}$ for any ideals $I,J$ and any prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$.

**Gauss' lemma:** $\sqrt{\cont(UV)} = \sqrt{\cont(U) \cont(V)}$.
In words, "$U ↦ \cont(U)$ preserves products relatively to prime ideals".

*Proof.* Use the "adjoints preserve limits" trick, remarking that $\mathfrak{p}[x]$ is prime as soon as $\mathfrak{p}$ is.
$$\begin{align*}\cont(UV) ⊆ \mathfrak{p} &⇔ UV ⊆ \mathfrak{p}[x]\\
&⇔ U ⊆ \mathfrak{p}[x] ∨ V ⊆ \mathfrak{p}[x]\\
&⇔ \cont(U) ⊆ \mathfrak{p} ∨ \cont(V) ⊆ \mathfrak{p}\\
&⇔ \cont(U) \cont(V) ⊆ \mathfrak{p}\qquad\qquad\square\end{align*}$$

As a side note, it also makes me think of the theory of Hilbert spaces where one can prove that a map with an adjoint is additive with again the same trick : if $\newcommand{\inprod}[2]{\langle #1, #2 \rangle}\inprod{f(x)}{y} = \inprod{x}{g(y)}$ for all $x,y$, then $\inprod{f(a+b)}{y} = \inprod{a+b}{g(y)} = \inprod{a}{g(y)} + \inprod{b}{g(y)} = \inprod{f(a) + f(b)}{y}$. So by the analog of the Yoneda Lemma (injectivity of the map to the dual in the case of Hilbert space ; we also have density as in category theory...), we get that $f(a+b) = f(a)+f(b)$.

The product of ideals looks like a cartesian product and the "comma operation" looks like an internal hom. We can interpret morphisms from $S$ to $I$ as elements $x$ of the ring such that $xS ⊆ I$. For instance we have $I ⊆ J$ if and only if $(1) ⊆ J:I$. There *must* be something going on, it looks too much like things we do in logic with for instance the interpretation of intuitionistic logic with topological spaces.
What is going on and how to interpret more precisely Gauss' lemma, prime ideals, etc. in this context? Is there any reference about this?

Comment: Nice observations. These operations not only are “a bit like adjoints”, they *are* adjoints of Galois correspondences. In any case, “Does anyone have to say anything about it?” is really not a specific question, so I vote to close. (Not sure about the reason: “too broad”, “unclear what you’re asking”, “missing context”? I went for *too broad* …)

Comment: @k.stm Yes, you are right, they are adjoints. When I wrote this I was thinking about the case with Gauss' lemma, where it is not technically a universal property that we use, and also the fact that the product of ideals looks like a "cartesian product" and the comma operation like an "internal hom". This is what I meant when I said it is only an analogy and not "formal". I would like to know if there is any way to make it more formal. Like some logic in rings with ideals.

Comment: @k.stm I added more details to the question but really I don't feel like it is too broad. There have to be something going on here and I just would like to link it to the literature.

Comment: I have two questions about your question:
 1) I don’t see how you can interpret morphisms  from $S$ to $I$ as elements of $I : S$. In which category are you?
 2) What’s the interpretation of intuitionistic logic with topological spaces? (Is this some form of the Curry–Howard correspondence?)


So all in all, you want a precise, maybe category-theoretic interpretation of Gauß’ lemma in the style of “This functor preserves limits.” as you already roughly interpreted it? Maybe a neat category-theoretic framework to fit in *all* of your observation, is that it?

Comment: @k.stm Thank you for your interest. 1) It's not morphisms from $S$ to $I$ that we interpret as elements of $I:S$. It is the *internal hom* that we interpret as $I:S$. We are in the poset category where the objects are ideals of the ring and they are ordered by inclusion (see Quiaochu's answer).

Comment: 2) The interpretation of intuitionistic logic with topological space says that you look at the category of open subsets of a topological space. You interpret the implication by inclusion, the conjunction/disjunction in the obvious ways, the negation as the interior of the complement and the internal hom from $U$ to $V$ as the interior of [the complement of $U$] union $V$. Yes I would like a neat categorical framework to fit my observations, where we could interpret Gauß’ lemma from a logical point of view.

Comment: About the internal hom: Okay, but you literally wrote “We can interpret morphisms from $S$ to $I$ as elements $x$ of the ring such that $xS ⊆ I$.” Also you would need $S$ be an ideal to interpret $I : S$ as an internal hom, right? Just minor remarks, I didn’t get what you where hinting at …

Comment: @k.stm Yes this is right, this is sloppy but this was the intuition I had in mind. And actually this is not a minor remark, this is something interesting that I didn't noticed when writing. I will try to explain what I understand of the situation.

Comment: I don't know how to make it very precise but it is a bit like in the case of the category of Banach spaces: we have several notions of "morphisms", each corresponding to a different "forgetful functor". We can say that a morphisms of Banach spaces is a continuous linear maps *or* one with norm $≤1$. The first choice corresponds to the forgetful functor giving "all the points" as the underlying set and the second choice corresponds to the forgetful functor being "the unit ball". In both cases, the internal hom is the same.

Comment: The notions of isomorphisms in both categories are different (in the second one it means "isometric" and in the other one is is a looser notion). I didn't studied it so I don't know how this all fits together but I think we don't have just two categories sitting next to each others. I prefer to think of it as *one* object equipped with different notions of morphisms… There may be compatibility conditions for instances.

Comment: In the case of ideals it is a bit the same : we can say that the "underlying set" of $I$ is "$I$ as a set", or that it is the truth-value of $I=(1)$ (we could also think of $I≠0$ or other things like that, I don't know). In the second case, it gives the poset structure we get from inclusion.

Comment: @k.stm So in the category where we interpret morphisms as elements of $I:S$, we compose them by multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection of ideals forms a [poset](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/partial+order), and hence a category, under inclusion. The product of ideals is not the categorical product (that would be intersection), but it is a [monoidal structure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+category), and the comma operation is an internal hom in the monoidal sense, giving a [closed monoidal](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+monoidal+category) structure. (Note that if the monoidal structure were cartesian we would have a [Heyting algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Heyting+algebra), which give semantics for intuitionistic logic.) In fact we have a bit more, namely a [quantale](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quantale) structure. There is a kind of "quantum logic" related to these, hence the name; see [linear logic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/linear+logic).

---

I like your approach to Gauss's lemma; it's not one I've seen before. Let me see if I can say anything relevant to it. In general, if $f : R \to S$ is a map of commutative rings, we get a pullback / inverse image operation

$$f^{-1} : \text{Idl}(S) \ni I \mapsto f^{-1}(I) \in \text{Idl}(R)$$

sending an ideal $I \subseteq S$ to the inverse image $f^{-1}(I) \subseteq R$; this is ideal contraction. Contraction, regarded as a functor between categories (posets), always has a left adjoint

$$f_{\ast} : \text{Idl}(R) \ni J \mapsto (f(J)) \in \text{Idl}(S)$$

given by the ideal generated by the direct image; this is ideal extension. Applied to $f : R \to R[X]$, ideal extension sends an ideal $I \subseteq R$ to the ideal $I[X] \subseteq R[X]$, so your observation about contents says that in this case ideal extension has a *further* left adjoint given by the content operation. I don't know off the top of my head when this happens in general; it probably suffices for $S$ to be free over $R$, and perhaps it suffices for $S$ to be flat over $R$.

Comment: If the $R$-module $S$ is a flat module that satisfies the condition in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3381933/characterization-of-flat-modules-m-for-which-tensoring-with-m-preserves-arbi), then ideal extension will have a left adjoint.

Comment: If $R \rightarrow S$ is faithfully flat, or more generally universally injective, then ideal contraction is left adjoint to ideal extension, which also captures the $R \rightarrow R[x]$ case because contraction there coincides with the 'content operation' on extended ideals.

Comment: @Badam: that doesn't sound right to me. Ideal contraction for $R \to R[x]$ should send an ideal $I \subseteq R[x]$ to the ideal of constant terms of the elements of $I$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think there are three usual ways to get an $R$-ideal from an $R[x]$-ideal: (1) Contraction, which sends $R[x] \supseteq J \rightarrow J \cap R$ (2) Evaluation at $0$, which (I think) you were describing above, and (3) The contents operation.  In general they're all distinct, as is clear from looking at, say, $(2 + x) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x]$.  In my last comment I'd just meant to point out they all agree on ideals of the form $I[x]$ (i.e. extended ideals) and recover $I$, but that more generally this behavior is typical of extension-contraction for universally injective maps.