# Characterization of flat modules $M$ for which tensoring with $M$ preserves arbitrary intersections

Tags: modules, flatness

Tensoring with a flat module $M$ will always preserve finite intersections of submodules, but not necessarily infinite intersections.

So, my question is:

> Is there a known characterization of flat modules $M$ for which tensoring with $M$ preserves arbitrary intersections?

A sufficient but not necessary condition is that $M$ is a finitely generated projective module, since then tensoring with $M$ would be a continuous functor and hence preserve wide pullbacks and *a fortiori*, intersections of (possibly infinitely many) subobjects. But free modules show that the sufficient condition is not necessary.